# von Neumann entropy in a limiting case

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, textbook-and-exercises, entropy, information-theory

I am stuck with a question from the book Quantum theory by Asher Peres.

Excercise (9.11):

> Three different preparation procedures of a spin 1/2 particle are represented by the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0
> \end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\
> \pm \sqrt{3}
> \end{pmatrix}   $. If they are equally likely, the Shannon entropy is $\log{3}$, and the von Neumann entropy is $\log{2}$. Show that if there are $n$ such particles, all prepared in the same way, the von Neumann entropy asymptotically tends to $\log{3}$ when $n \to \infty$.

> **Hint**: Consider three real unit vectors making equal angles: $\langle u_i,u_j \rangle = c $ if $ i \neq j$ . Show that the eigenvalues of $\sum u_i u_i^\dagger$ are 1-c, 1-c and 1+2c."

The Shannon entropy can be easily calculated to be $\log{3}$. The density matrix
$
\hat\rho$ comes out to be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Therefore, the von Neumann entropy also comes out to be $\log{2}$. However, in the second part, I am not able to get von Neumann entropy equal to $\log{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first prove the hint.

Consider three $d$- dimensional unit vectors $u_i$ and define $ A = \sum_{i=1}^{3} u_i u_i^{\dagger} $.

A simple calculation shows that
\begin{align*} 
A \big(u_1 + u_2 + u_3\big) & = (u_1 + c\cdot u_2 + c\cdot u_3) + (c\cdot u_1 + u_2 + c\cdot u_3) + ( c\cdot u_1 + c\cdot u_2 + u_3) \\ 
&= (1 + 2c) \cdot \big(u_1 + u_2 + u_3\big)
\end{align*}
meaning $ \xi = u_1 + u_2 + u_3 $ is an eigenvector of $ A $ with $ 1 + 2c $ eigenvalue.

A similar calculation shows that
$$ 
A \big(u_1 - u_2\big) = (1 - c) \cdot \big(u_1 - u_2\big), \hspace{1.5em} 
A \big(u_1 - u_3\big) = (1 - c) \cdot \big(u_1 - u_3\big)
$$
Thus we have found 3-linear independent eigenvectors with eigenvalues $ 1-c, 1-c, 1+2c $.
The other $ d - 3 $ eigenvalues are, of course, zero with eigenvectors  orthogonal to $ V = \text{span}\{u_1, u_2, u_3\} $.

This means that the Von-Neumann entropy of the density matrix $ \rho = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{3} u_i u_i^{\dagger} $ is
\begin{align*}
S_{\rho} = 
&- 2 \cdot \frac{1 - c}{3} \cdot \text{log}\big( \frac{1 - c}{3} \big) 
- \frac{1 + 2c}{3} \cdot \text{log}\big( \frac{1 + 2c}{3} \big) \\= 
&- 2 \cdot \frac{1 - c}{3} \cdot \text{log}\big(1 - c\big) 
- \frac{1 + 2c}{3} \cdot \text{log}\big(1 + 2c\big) + \text{log}(3)
\end{align*}
and so $ S_{\rho} \to  \text{log}(3) $ if $ c \to 0 $.

Why is this enough?

Because for n particles the states are
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes n} $,  $\frac{1}{2^n} \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
\pm \sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}^{\otimes n} $
with dot product $ v_i^{\dagger} v_j = \big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)^n $ for $ i \neq j $, so $ c \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $